# Tails OS - Modifying boot options

Tags: boot, tails-os

When Tails OS boots, you can press tab to modify the startup options. Is there any way I can save an iso with these options already set? It's a real pain to have to press tab and set them up every time. Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chainload the ISO's bootloader using `syslinux`, then you can add all the extra parameters you need. Use the actual contents of the `syslinux` directory in the ISO as a base.

There are many examples online. Check [*Create a GNU/Linux multiboot USB-Stick (Live USB) with Syslinux chainloading*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140706173717/http://fomori.org/blog/?p=747) (now only available in the web-archive).

Comment: The link is gone. That's why answers should not be links, but *answers*, I guess.

Comment: @U.Windl I replacedthe link with one for the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 5):

There's actually another way to do it by remounting the live disk as writable

```
mount -o remount -w /lib/live/mount/medium
```

and then editing the live config file corresponding to your architecture (either `live.cfg`, `live486.cfg` or `liveamd64.cfg`)  under `/lib/live/mount/medium/syslinux`
more info [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sohhlz/wiki/index/tails-usb-fixed-disk)

Comment: Trying to follow the link I got "**This subreddit was banned due to being unmoderated.**". Please don't add links as answers!

Comment: I did `sudo mount -o remount -w /lib/live/mount/medium` but configuration files located in `/lib/live/mount/medium/syslinux` are still read only ...

Comment: @U.Windl - The info in the link is somewhat outdated, but can still be found here: http://web.archive.org/web/20200317040754/https://www.reddit.com/r/sohhlz/wiki/index/tails-usb-fixed-disk

Comment: The main files to edit for Syslinux on Tails 5.3 are now: `live.cfg` on 32 bit and `live64.cfg` on 64 bit systems. The mount command in a root terminal still works the same and the path for syslinux has not changed.

Answer (score 2):

This path is incorrect for Tails. Actually I believe that the actual config files are here

`/lib/live/mount/medium/EFI/BOOT` which I have changed `live.cfg` and `live64.cfg` and this works.  Re-boot and inspect the config file and see your changes.

Comment: What is "this path" in your answer?

Comment: Your path is not valid (any more) for either Grub or Syslinux. There are currently no configuration files in the folder you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Tails 4.5 uses grub:
Path to change grub boot options:
/lib/live/mount/medium/efi/debian

Comment: I notice that this answer is only slightly different from [Stephen's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448951/117549); can you explain why the /debian directory is preferred to /BOOT as mentioned in their answer?

Comment: In tails 4.5 there are two boot options: syslinux or grub
https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/boot_options/index.en.html
Grub is the new one.
So syslinux: /lib/live/mount/medium/EFI/BOOT (live.cfg & live64.cfg)
Grub: /lib/live/mount/medium/efi/debian (grub.cfg)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me on Tails 4.5. In my case I have a 2015 MacBook Pro that I wanted to use Tails 4.5 on but kept getting a partially garbled desktop menu, except when I added the below boot option to Grub settings

intel_iommu=off

(Above boot option was taken from the instructions under "Graphics corruption in Tor Browser and Thunderbird" [here](https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html#graphics-corruption-tor-browser))

Anyway the steps I followed were:

1. Started Tails with the admin password activated
2. In Applications > System Tools > Root Terminal, entered the command
   lines

> ```
> sudo mount -o remount -w /lib/live/mount/medium
> sudo nano /lib/live/mount/medium/efi/debian/grub.cfg
> ```

3. The grub.cfg file has 3 separate sections with a line that starts with `linux /live/vmlinuz initrd=/live`. I added a space and that boot option
   at the end of each of these lines and saved the file.
4. Rebooted to machine to test.